# How to read compressed TSV files (*.gtf.gz) with rust-polars?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

Complete rust beginner here coming from python.
I would like to use rust-polars to read a compressed GTF (*.gtf.gz) file:

```rust
    let schema = Arc::new(Schema::new(vec![
        Field::new("contigName", DataType::Categorical),
        Field::new("source", DataType::Utf8),
        Field::new("feature", DataType::Categorical),
        Field::new("start", DataType::Int64),
        Field::new("end", DataType::Int64),
        Field::new("score", DataType::Float32),
        Field::new("strand", DataType::Categorical),
        Field::new("frame", DataType::Categorical),
        Field::new("attribute", DataType::Utf8),
    ]));

    let mut df = CsvReader::from_path(r).unwrap()
        .with_delimiter(b'\t')
        .with_schema(&schema)
        .with_comment_char(Some(b'#'))
        .with_n_threads(Some(1)) // comment for multithreading
        .with_encoding(CsvEncoding::LossyUtf8)
        .has_header(false)
        .finish()?;

    let test = df.head(Some(10));
    println!("{}", test);
```

However, I end up with a number of issues:

- **How to tell Polars that the file is compressed?**
  I tried passing `io::BufReader::new(GzDecoder::new(f))` instead of the file, but that fails.
- **How to parse Categorical columns?**
- **How to handle possibly missing or additional columns?**
- **How to read a file which has '#' as header and '##' as comment?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there are a few questions here at once. I will try to answer the ones I can.

> How to tell Polars that the file is compressed?

You don't have to. You only have to compile polars with the `decompress` or `decompress-fast` feature flag. (The firs one is rust native, the latter needs a c-compiler).

> How to parse Categorical columns

You set the schema to `DataType::Categorical`, or you first parse as `Utf8` and then cast later.

```rust
df.may_apply("some_utf8_column", |s| s.cast(&DataType::Categorical));
```

> How to handle possibly missing or additional columns?

I don't know what you mean by handle?

> How to read a file which has '#' as header and '##' as comment?

Polars currently only allows a single comment char. You can set this comment char and every line that starts with this character will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! 
- "How to handle possibly missing or additional columns?" The file might have additional columns that I do not know beforehand. Would something like "if 'asdf' in df.columns: do_sth(df)" be possible?
- "Polars currently only allows a single comment char": Would it be possible to open the file manually and remove all "^##" lines from the stream?